# Команды или нет? Что такое [ -d $mydir ] в баш?

Tags: linux, bash

Интересует что такое:

```
if [ -z "${var// }" ]...

if [ -d $mydir ]...
```

А точнее что такое -z и -d? Как это грамотно называется и где можно почитать про них? И где найти полный список этих "ключей"?

Comment: `man test`. А чем вы полъзовались?

Comment: Помимо man test в командной строке. Можно в редакторе (IDE) документацию вызвать. К примеру, в emacs можно [`helm-dash`](https://github.com/areina/helm-dash) использовать. И/или на телефоне есть Dash app. Похожий интерфейс доступен online/offline: [devdocs.io](http://devdocs.io/fish~2.6/commands#test). Полезно ещё в гугле можно: [man bash test](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это условные выражения.
`-z` - будет `True`, если аргумент строка и её длина ровна 0
`-d` - будет `True`, если это каталог и он существует

Почитать можно, набрав в консоли: `man bash`